# Color shader driver help

Tags: armature, shaders, drivers, shader-nodes, custom-properties

I want to make a driver that changes the color in a mix color node from one color to another color using a custom property on a rig. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Without any further detail what you exactly want to do: create a custom property on the armature object, right-click on it and choose _Copy as New Driver_, go to the _Mix Color_ node, right-click on the mix factor and choose _Paste Driver_. Then right-click on it again and choose _Edit Driver_ and create a formula or some kind of relation how you want the property to affect the mix factor.

Comment: I have two set colors that I want to switch between with a custom property.